# change text in cart woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have used the wordpress with woocommerce. I have used the following code in functions.php to show how many items in cart.

```
<?php
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
global $woocommerce;
ob_start();
?>
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
<?php

$fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

return $fragments;


}
?>
```

Header.php:

```
 <?php global $woocommerce;?> 
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">
<?php
 echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

If there is no product in the cart it shows 0items-$0. Instead i need to show the text "Your Basket is Empty". I am a newbie and don't know how to do this using that function. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the code in the header.php to the following,

```
<?php global $woocommerce;?> 
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">
<?php
if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
     echo _e("Your Basket is Empty.");
}
else{
     echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
} ?></a>
```